# How to save a file to be able to load it with "data()", for example data(iris)?

Tags: r

I wonder how to save a file to be able to load it with "data()", for example data(iris)?

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

.
.

Answer (score 1):

`data()` is loading package-dependent objects that are usually used for package demonstration. This kind of data is stored in a package subdirectory packagename/data. Check [Writing R Extensions 1.1.6 Data in packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) for more details.